# Are the spices sumac, harissa and za’atar related in any way to capsicums/ chillies?

Tags: substitutions

I cannot cook with them until I know as I am allergic to all forms of capsicums.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  There is a good answer to your question below; if it satisfies you, please check the check mark.

Comment: What do you mean "all forms of capsicums"? There's only one form of capsicum? Is this one of those British/American English things again? I thought that Americans called capsicums "bell peppers"?

Comment: @nick012000 The capsicum family in a botanical sense encompass many fruits from the capsicum/bell pepper/pepper (location dependent) to hot and not so hot chillies : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum so anything in that family will be dangerous to the OP

Comment: Note that we can answer on the botanical relationship, but this is not a deterministic predictor of an allergy - you may be allergic to a plant that is not closely related, if it happens to produce the same chemical element to which you react, or to not have a reaction to a single plant out of a whole family.

Answer (score 12):

Sumac is not related to chillies.

Harissa contains chillies.

Za'atar is a spice/herb blend, it should not have chillies in it, but every blend can be different, check the ingredient lists before buying.

Comment: One thing to add: Sumac is not closely related to any plant you are likely to have eaten before. So it has the same risk of food allergies as any new (to you) food. If you are prone to severe food allergies, you may want to take a cautious approach, such as following the steps of the [universal allergy test](https://www.backpacker.com/skills/universal-edibility-test).

Comment: @csk Sumac is actually (as I'm suprised to read) closely related to Cashews (Anacardiaceae). Cashew allergy certainly seems quite common.

Comment: @Max Harissa does contain a lot chili, but also other spices, so maybe it's not a good idea to just describe it as a chili blend on an allergy question.

Comment: @leftaroundabout but on a question regarding allergies to members of the capsicum family, which includes chillies, it is very pertinent to mention it as chilli blend

Comment: Perhaps phrase it as "harissa contains a blend of chillies"?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers to my question. I’ll give harissa a miss then and check za’atar when buying.

Comment: Georgie, if that answer is good enough for you, click the check mark to accept it.

Comment: Za'atar varies, but almost always contains Sumac.